# Is there a practical use of conductance?

Tags: conductance

What is the reason that conductance exists? Is there a practical reason to use conductance (G = 1 / R [Siemens]) instead of resistance (ohm) or does it only have value for theoretical reasons (which I can't find/understand)?

Comment: It's a number. So you can write `I=VG` instead of `I=V/R`.

Comment: Nope. There's no reason for it, at all. They just made it up to confuse people and keep them from deciding to become an electronics engineer. They also made up resistivity instead of resistance and conductivity along with conductance, all of which is there to hassle your brain until it fizzles. ;) ... Of course, there are good reasons for it. You just need to be exposed to them from time to time, is all. :) Don't worry about it until it comes up in some problem, though.

Comment: You're probably at the start of your studies. You'll see plenty of usage of conductance. It's very often the more practical term than resistance. anyway, what is more "practical" is pure opinion - vote to close as asking for opinions.

Comment: It's no more or less useful than resistance is.

Comment: It's useful for nodal analysis because it makes the equations easier to manipulate. Thus anything that uses nodal analysis benefits from this. For example, in power systems analysis, we use admittance (analogous to conductance but in AC) to directly write the node equations by inspection.

Answer (score 7):

Of course it's not "required" but it's convenient at times for practical and computational reasons.

For very high resistances, for example. My ancient Fluke 8026B meter has a maximum resistance range of 19.9M\$\Omega\$.  It also has a conductance range of 200nS full scale, so a reading of 0.01nS conductance represents a resistance of 100G\$\Omega\$, and I can get 2-3 digit resolution of the equivalent of 1-10G\$\Omega\$, which is quite useful for measuring leakage and such like.

Parallel conductances simply add like series resistances, so if you have n resistors in parallel, the resulting conductance G is just G1 + G2 +...+ Gn.

Similarly, admittance (the reciprocal of impedance) is useful at times.

Answer (score 5):

Conductance and resistance are different ways of looking at the same property. In some cases it makes sense to think of resisting electrical current and in others it makes sense to think of conducting electrical current.

> Using conductance instead of resistance for the same physical object simply emphasizes a different aspect of its behavior. Resistance reduces or impedes current flow, while conductance allows current to pass through. The terms are two aspects of the same idea. Source: [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-circuit-analysis-topic/ee-resistor-circuits/a/ee-parallel-conductance).

Ohm's law is now rewritten as \$ i = vG \$ where \$ G \$ is the conductance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWxOZq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Parallel conductances are also much simpler to calculate than parallel resistors.*

In my limited experience, conductances are often used with liquids.

Answer (score 5):

Some physical effects are proportional to conductance, (inversely proportional to resistance). In such cases, plotting that effect vs. conductance gives you a straight line, when plotting it vs. resistance would give you a curved line. A linear curve displays any non-linearities more clearly (Compared to a 1/x curve) making it more desirable.

For a trivial example, if you want to plot current at a fixed voltage, plotting the current vs conductance gives you a straight line.

Answer (score 3):

Conductance may not be a mainstay in practical engineering. However, you may encounter it more often in circuit theory, physics and physical chemistry.
Electrolytes are almost always characterized by their conductivity. As an example the purity of DI (de-ionized) water is commonly characterized by its conductivity.
[Wikipedia: Electrolytic Conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductivity_(electrolytic))

Answer (score 2):

Conductance is very handy when dealing with acoustic transducers. From conductance you get an idea of the operating frequency band and bandwidth of the transducer where transmit performance is best. The conductance plot will also show the frequency bands where unwanted mechanical resonances caused by the surrounding structure are located.

When modeling transducer impedance/admittance in SPICE, you can make a tricky subcircuit using an admittance table to simulate the transducer admittance/impedance versus frequency. I have used the following two-terminal subcircuit in PSpice and LTspice for .AC analysis (doesn't work for transient analysis). There is a way to use impedance data in a similar subcircuit which can be found on the Internet. The syntax for this can be found in the PSpice Reference Guide. LTspice doesn't cover the syntax for *voltage controlled current source* tables.

```
*Subckt simulates admittance versus frequency
*Data format: Freq(Hz)  G(mhos)  B(mhos)
.SUBCKT XDCRZ 1 2
G1 2 1 FREQ {V(2,1)}= R_I (
+  10000.000     2.62097E-06   8.34752E-05
+  10315.608     2.77835E-06   8.66755E-05
+  10641.178     2.90038E-06   8.89285E-05
+ )
.ENDS XDCRZ
```